# IIS hosting, asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Hi I have a site that uses flex and calls controller actions which returns json to the flex. This works fine in a dev server , the folder that has the flex app lives inside the web project and in the dev ennvironment, makes calls hostname, ie www.someurl.com

in the actual live scenario, this will be an intranet so not hostname to call, the flex app seems to have trouble calling http://localhost/Virtual directory name

it seems to totally miss the virtual directory name. I am obviously missing something basic, any help?

Im thinking moving the flex app folder out and hosting as a separate app, might make it work

Answer (score 0):

The Flex app is going to run on the client machine. When Flex does a lookup for localhost, it will try to find the service running on the client's PC and not your server.

You need to change localhost to the fully qualified domain name of your Intranet server. That way the Flex app will call the service on your server instead of the client pc.

Comment: can you give me an example of the fully qualified domain name, Thanks

Comment: like this? http:/ServerName.DomainName

Comment: www.myflexdomain.com/jsonVirtualDirectory